# How to find a bug from the SpringVaadinServlet class?

Tags: vaadin

In our Vaadin app, an error will occur when sorting entries on the UI. Based on the error stack, I insert all possible debugging points in the methods of the `MyServlet` class. And none of them shows the error enter point. It is likely a problem in its superclass `SpringVaadinServlet`. How to find out whether it is caused by a data error or something else?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
            at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:353) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:500) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator.fetchItemsWithRange(DataCommunicator.java:379) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator.sendDataToClient(DataCommunicator.java:341) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator.beforeClientResponse(DataCommunicator.java:316) ~[vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlWriter.write(UidlWriter.java:126) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:124) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445) [vaadin-server-8.5.2.jar:8.5.2]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
            at $javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5ddc88f8.invoke(<generated>) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:?]
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
            at com.abc.myapp.ui.MyServlet$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beeb36e1.service(<generated>) [classes/:?]
```

and the `MyServlet` class is defined as the following:

```java
    @Component("vaadinServlet")
    @WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = DiscoveryUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public class MyServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: The error comes from "com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator.fetchItemsWithRange(DataCommunicator.java:379)" - but instead of trying to debug, you should update all your dependencies. All components are end of life and have literally no support. (Vaadin, Spring Boot and Tomcat shown here)

Comment: @Knoobie Thanks. That actually is what I try to do after posting the question. According to https://mvnrepository.com, I update Vaadin version from 8.5.2  to the current version 8.16.0. Unfortunately, the problem still occurs. Shall I file a bug report?

Comment: The last non-commercial version is 8.14.3 - I would suggest to place your debug Statements in  the DataCommunicator to check why the error happens. An GitHub issue is more likely to be fixed with a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: That would request to modify and build the Vaadin project, right? I put a log configuration to a Spring's application.yml file logging.level.com.vaadin.data.provider DEBUG but don't see any more log messages.

Comment: This is not a bug in Vaadin. The problem is that what ever your data object is, it does not fullfill contract for comparison needed for sorting.

Comment: @TatuLund Thanks very much for your tip. Someone in our company also mentions that it is cause by Java comparator implementation. As someone who doesn't have any knowledge of Vaadin, I don't know what he is talking about. After some quick study, I regonize that a column can have a comparator by using the setComparator. The data of the column is boolean. So, I need to add the setComparator to the column.

Answer (score 0):

To make this question useful for others who run into the some problem, I answer my own question. As Tatu points out, the problem isn't in Vaadin, but how to use it properly. I solve the problem by add the setComparator method for the column.